# JTable Rowborder?

Tags: java, jtable, row, border, renderer

I wanna make a lineborder for a WHOLE ROW !
Not only for one cell,.. i have different cellrenderers but i wanna make a border around these cells in one row..

any idea? is there a DefaultRowRenderer, or something else?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Table Row Renderering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) shows one approach for this without creating custom renderers.

Answer (score 1):

If your cell renderer was smart enough not to draw the right hand side when in column 0, and not draw the left hand side when in column n - 1, then it would effectively look like a row border.

Comment: yea i now,.. but is there a border for that?
i will proof it for myself ;)